# Uso de Formación Ocupacional

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, legislación

Si alguien asistió a algunas clases de traducción en una compañía en la que no trabaja, ¿se puede considerar eso "formación ocupacional"? Es que no estoy segura de los significados que puede tener esta frase.

Comment: Necesitaríamos más contexto, para empezar el país en el que consideras este caso. Temo, sin embargo, que esto sea algo más de derecho laboral que de lengua.

Comment: @fedorqui es posible, aunque analizar términos lingüísticos sobre derecho es algo que podríamos hacer. A fin de cuentas, la RAE ya tiene un buscador de términos del español jurídico (que es otra rama del español); no veo por qué nosotros no habríamos de recorrer ese camino.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo mientras no nos empiecen a llegar recursos para saber si algo es constitucional... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leo en [esta página](http://formadores-ocupacionales.blogspot.com.es/2009/10/formacion-ocupacional-que-es.html) que:

> La formación profesional ocupacional, está dirigida a las personas en edad laboral que quieren prepararse para acceder a una ocupación o promocionarse en un puesto de trabajo.

Según esto, el sitio donde se impartan las clases es lo de menos: lo importante es el objetivo que persigues recibiendo esas clases. Si tu objetivo es formarte para poder optar a un puesto de trabajo (ya sea porque estás en paro o porque aspiras a algo mejor), es formación ocupacional.

Esos cursos los puedes dar por tu cuenta en centros especializados, o los puede dar tu propia empresa (si está interesada en formar a sus empleados) a través de profesores contratados. Pero insisto en que lo importante es lo que persigues con ello.

Comment: ¡Ah! Muchas gracias, Carlos, por su respuesta, y gracias a todos. No es por algo de derecho jaja, es sólo para ponerlo en un CV. :) Gracias.